# FlowListView Column Spacing

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I using Flowlistview to show 5 images in Horizontal position, but the default spacing between columns is too big, how can I reduce the spacing and increase the pictures sizes?

Below is what I have done :

[image]

My flowlist code is like this:

```
<controls:FlowListView   HeightRequest="70"  HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="0,5,0,0" FlowColumnMinWidth="70" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="True" FlowItemsSource="{Binding Feedbackitems}"  FlowLastTappedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" >
            <controls:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:FlowStackCell Padding="0">
                    <StackLayout >
                            <forms:CachedImage HeightRequest="66"  WidthRequest="66"  DownsampleUseDipUnits="false"  Source="{Binding ImgEmojiSelected}" IsVisible="False" IsEnabled="false">
                                <forms:CachedImage.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger TargetType="forms:CachedImage" Binding="{Binding Selected, Converter={StaticResource cnvInvert}}" Value="ImgEmojiSelected">
                                        <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
                                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </forms:CachedImage.Triggers>
                            </forms:CachedImage>
                            <forms:CachedImage  HeightRequest="66" WidthRequest="66"  DownsampleUseDipUnits="false"  Source="{Binding ImgEmojiUnSelected}" IsVisible="False" IsEnabled="false">
                            <forms:CachedImage.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger TargetType="forms:CachedImage" Binding="{Binding Selected, Converter={StaticResource cnvInvert}}" Value="ImgEmojiUnSelected">
                                    <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </forms:CachedImage.Triggers>
                        </forms:CachedImage>
                    </StackLayout>
                    </controls:FlowStackCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        </controls:FlowListView>
```

Comment: [Assuming](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView) try adding Spacing in StackLayout and FlowStackCell (inheriting from StackLayout)

Comment: I tried spacing= 0 or -6 , doesnt do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use something like this, in order to wrap the stacklayout into the FlowListView and define the padding you wish between the images. If I have understood right your issue, this worked for me.

```
<controls:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="3" 
                       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"                           
                       SeparatorVisibility="Default" 
                       RowHeight="160"
                       Margin="7"
                       FlowItemsSource="{Binding Photos}">
    
    <controls:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <StackLayout Padding="3" >
                <Image Source="{Binding PersonalPhoto}"                        
                       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                       Aspect="AspectFill"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
</controls:FlowListView>
```